# Some questions about rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

All rings are commutative and unital

**Q1:** what means notation
$$A\cong A_1\times\ldots\times A_n?$$
Is it true that elements of $A_1\times\ldots\times A_n$ are collection of elements of $A_1,\ldots ,A_n$ with termwise multiplication and addition? What is the difference between
$$A_1\times\ldots\times A_n$$
and
$$A_1\oplus\ldots\oplus A_n?$$

**Q2:** Let's $\{\mathfrak{m}_i\}_{i\in I}$ is the set of all maximal ideals of ring $A$. Is it true that $\cup_{i\in I}\mathfrak{m}_i$ consists of all non-invertible elements and $A-\{\mathfrak{m}_i\}_{i\in I}$ consists of all invertible elements?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For 1: There is essentially no difference between the direct product and direct sum of rings for a finite index set.

Comment: For 2: Yes, and I think you must apply Zorn's lemma.

Answer (score 6):

**Q1**. Yes, the direct product is always meant by $n$-tuples and coordinatewise operations. For finite $n$ and for rings(!!), it is true that
$A_1\times\ldots\times A_n \cong A_1\oplus\ldots\oplus A_n$.
For infinite $n$, the right-hand side contains only those elements who has only finitely many nonzero coordinates.

**Q2**. If an element $a$ is invertible, then the ideal $\langle a\rangle$ generated by it, contains $1$, so contains all $A$, hence $a\in A\setminus\{\mathfrak m_i\}_i $.

On the other hand, if $a$ is not invertible, then $\langle a\rangle = Aa$ doesn't contain $1$, then --using Zorn lemma-- it can be extended to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_i$.

Comment: The direct sum of infinitely many rings is not even a ring.